# After webpack build background image lost id svg-path.svg#id

Tags: css, webpack, next.js, sass

I use nextjs.

I have styles like:

```scss
.img {
    background-image: url(path/to/my/svg/file.svg#icon);
}
```

When I run `npm run dev`
I got next styles for my element with class name "img":

```css
.img {
    background-image: url(path/to/my/svg/file.jsbf730sh.svg);
}
```

I lost `#icon` id.

I assume this is because of scss compiler, but cannot solve it.

Comment: Are you using purge.css? I'm not sure if it applicable, but I've experienced similar behavior and needed to whitelist the missing classes/ids in webpack. https://v1.purgecss.com/whitelisting

Answer (score 0):

you should use the `generator.filename` with the `[fragment]` substitution in the Webpack module rule for SVG:

```js
module: {
  rules: [
    {
      test: /\.(png|jpe?g|ico|svg)$/,
      type: 'asset/resource',
      generator: {
        // use the '[fragment]' to keep it in output filename, e.g. icons.svg#home
        filename: 'img/[name].[hash:8][ext][fragment][query]',
      },
    },
  ],
},
```

Comment: Unfortunately, it does not help. I tried to change hash size and I see changes, but not for [fragment].

Comment: @mr_alex are you using the plugins: html-webpack-plugin / mini-css-extract-plugin?

Comment: I looked into the nexjs deep and I found mini-css-extract-plugin, so I think yes